# Trouble reading Windows Live Contacts Api results in php

Tags: php, contacts, windows-live

I am using [windows live contacts api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx) to create find a friend functionality in a PHP 5 application. I am able to get the results fine but it's encoded "deflate". I have tried using gzuncompress to decompress but it returns false. If any one has experience using this api with php 5 and can help that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I wish i could delete this question. I was using the wrong function (or more specifically Zend Framework had a bug in it where it used gzuncrompress where it should have been using gzinflate).